# Convert single quote to separators in the url_title function in CodeIgniter

Tags: regex, codeigniter-3, slug, slugify

In CodeIgniter, the *url_title* function takes a "title" string as input and creates a human-friendly URL string with a "separator" (dash or underscore).

Currently, the function remove single quote. In french, the single quote (apostrophe) is a word separator.

For example : The expected slug for "**L'apostrophe**" is "**l-apostrophe**", and not "**lapostrophe**" as it is currently the output of the *url_title* function.

I would like to update the following source code (*/system/helpers/url_helper.php* - line 493):

```
$trans = array(
    '&.+?;'         => '',
    '[^\w\d _-]'        => '',
    '\s+'           => $separator,
    '('.$q_separator.')+'   => $separator
);
```

Since but I'm not familiar with RegEx, it would be nice if someone could help me to add single quote in the array `$trans` in order to convert single quotes into separators.

Comment: Try changing `[^\w\d _-]` to `[^\w\d' _-]` and `\s+` to `[\s']+`

Comment: It does not work, because RegEx is already in quotes.

Comment: And if you try to escape it? `[^\w\d\' _-]` and `[\s\']+`

Comment: Yes it works, and changing single quotes for double quotes also do the job. But I prefer to escape it as you suggested. Could you briefly explain the mechanism behind this two lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the CodeIgniter core is always a problem to ensure upgrade and compatibility with future versions. I would better suggest to update the array of foreign characters for transliteration | conversion used by the Text helper (in */application/config/foreign_chars.php*).

Add the following line at the end of the array:

```
'/\'/' => ' '
```

This will convert single quotes (`'/\'/'`) to spaces (`' '`) when calling the `convert_accented_characters` function.

Answer (score 1):

You might replace `[^\w\d _-]` with `[^\w\d' _-]` and `\s+` with `[\s']+`

This pattern `[^\w\d _-]` is a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match a `'` and will be replaced by an empty string. If you add `'` to the existing character class then is will not be matched and not be replaced.

`\s+` matches 1+ whitespace characters and those will be replaced by the separator. You could turn that into a character class `[\s']+` and repeat that 1+ times. Then what will be matched here will be replaced by the `$separator`

Escape the `\'` in your example as the regex is between single quotes already.